# Count repeated objets in document in mongo

Tags: mongodb, codeigniter-3

I have this type of data where i want to count repeated objects according to string

```
{

    "version":"2.0",
    "type":"DevicesSeen",
    "data":{
        "observations":[
            {
                "manufacturer":"Apple"
            },
            {
                "manufacturer":"GUANGDONG OPPO MOBILE..."
            },
            {
                "manufacturer":"Apple"
            }
        ]
    }

}
```

I want count of the manufacturer
example
Apple :2
Samsung :1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$data.observations"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$data.observations.manufacturer",
            counts: {$sum :1}
        }
    }
 ])
```

The result will be as below:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "GUANGDONG OPPO MOBILE...",
    "counts" : 1
},

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "Apple",
    "counts" : 2
}
```

Comment: Thanks worked Like Charm. Can we sum the Count result according to condition with '_id' in same query